# Trouble with Perfect Scrollbar

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, scrollbar, perfect-scrollbar

I'm using the Perfect Scrollbar jQuery app (http://www.yuiazu.net/perfect-scrollbar/) for this site:

http://thehummingbirdplace.com/

The scrollbar shows up when you hover over the News section, but it won't scroll down to reveal the content. I've used this scrollbar before successfully, so I'm stumped as to what is different now. I haven't been able to replicate this on a simpler page, when I experiment on another page it either works or just vanishes, so I'm not sure why it is successfully showing up, yet not scrolling on the main page.

I've tried taking out the second use of jQuery on the page too, just in case, but I get the same result.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the set up for the jQuery.noConflict(); command and has now been fixed